# How to use list-formatter example for ng2-auto-complete?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, typeahead

I'm trying to use the list-formatter feature for ng2-auto-complete but unable to find a good example of how this is implemented. I have the following code so far:

```
<input class="form-control input-list" ng2-auto-complete
      [(ngModel)]="model4"
      placeholder="Search"
      [source]="googleGeoCode"
      list-formatter="myListFormatter"
      path-to-data=""
      value-property-name=null
      display-property-name=null
      min-chars="2"
      />

export class HomeComponent {

  templateStr: any = templateStr;
  valuePropertyName: string;
  displayPropertyName: string;

  googleGeoCode: string = "http://localhost:61227/machine/?query=:keyword";

  myListFormatter(data: any): string {
        let html: string = "";
        html += data[this.valuePropertyName] ? `<b>(${data[this.valuePropertyName]})</b>` : "";
        html += data[this.displayPropertyName] ? `<span>${data[this.displayPropertyName]}</span>` : data;
        return html;
      }

 }
```

So, how can I get the list-formatter to work?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question ;)

Comment: What's the current behavior and what's the expected behavior?

Answer (score 6):

The list-formatter attribute name has to be inside brackets, like so:

```
[list-formatter]="myListFormatter"
```

The `this.valuePropertyName` in your function is not gonna get recognized either. You have to put in there a key of your data object inside quotes.

I think the defaults are 'id' and 'value'. Try `data['id']` and `data['value']`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure from where the data will passed into listformatter function later got to know that **data** will be passed from the **datalist** passed into input.

```
myListFormatter(data: any): string {
        let html: string = "";
        html += data[this.valuePropertyName] ? `<b>(${data[this.valuePropertyName]})</b>` : "";
        html += data[this.displayPropertyName] ? `<span>${data[this.displayPropertyName]}</span>` : data;
        return html;
      }
```